# pilon error, file .bam must be indexed BAM

Tags: bioinformatics, bam

I have an error to do this:

After Flye assembly I obtain the file assembly_DG_1.fasta

The I used:

```
bwa index assembly_DG_1.fasta 
bwa mem -pt16 assembly_DG_1.fasta DG_1_R1_001_val_1.fq.gz DG_1_R2_001_val_2.fq.gz | samtools sort -m4G -@4 -o align.bam -
```

Afterwards I used pilon:

```
pilon --genome flye_corrected_DG_1/assembly_DG_1.fasta --bam align.bam
```

ERROR: align.bam must be indexed BAM

Comment: Well... did you index the bam?

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-index.html

Comment: ok..
I used
samtools index -bc align.bam
and then
pilon --genome flye_corrected_DG_1/assembly_DG_1.fasta --bam align.bam

It works!

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
samtools index -bc align.bam
```

and then

```
pilon --genome flye_corrected_DG_1/assembly_DG_1.fasta --bam align.bam
```

Solved the problem.